# Using jQuery to validate JSON input into a form textarea field

Tags: jquery, json, validation

How can JSON input into a form textarea field be validated using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var theJson = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).val())
```

quick example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zsKEg/3/).

Comment: Update many years later: [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) is deprecated. You should use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead.